# Use node edit form layout for other entity types

Tags: 8, theming, group

The node edit form got a nice overhaul for Drupal 8's default admin theme, whereby a lot of the metadata fields like Revisions, Meta Tags, URL Aliases, Publish status, Promote status, etc are moved into a sidebar.

I'm using the Group module, and have enabled metatag integration and revisions via patch from [#2829966](https://www.drupal.org/i/2829966).

Currently however the meta tags and revisions appear in a vertical tabs block at the bottom of the edit form, making the page extra long.

How can I get those items into a sidebar like the Node edit form does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Drupal\node\NodeForm` provides it own `build()` method that puts the meta items into an  `advanced` group, and then the `classy` template `node-edit-form.html.twig` renders that group in a sidebar. The form builder also attaches the `node/drupal.node` library, which provides the layout CSS.

To copy this layout and style for another entity, you could implement `hook_form_alter` in a custom module and move the metadata form items into an `advanced` group like `NodeForm` does. You also need to theme the form with the `node_edit_form` template and attach the `node/drupal.node` library.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Select the group add/edit form.
  if (in_array('group_form', $form['#theme'])) {
    // Use the node edit form template.
    $form['#theme'][] = 'node_edit_form';

    // Use the node form layout library.
    $form['#attached']['library'] = ['node/drupal.node'];

    // Create the advanced element if it doesn't exist.
    if (!isset($form['advanced'])) {
      $form['advanced'] = [
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#weight' => 99,
      ];
    }
    else {
      // Make 'advanced' a container instead of vertical_tabs.
      $form['advanced']['#type'] = 'container';
    }

    // Add the style class to tell the admin theme how to style it.
    $form['advanced']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'entity-meta';

    // Move detail elements into 'advanced'.
    $form['detail_element_you_want_to_move']['#group'] = 'advanced';
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could create your own Twig template and library and use those instead of borrowing from `node`.

Comment: Your example code is not entirely correct: The `advanced` element may not exist in group forms, so it should be added then instead of the `entity-meta` class only. Also, moving all elements to `meta` will cause them to appear as header of the sidebar (see the `entity-meta__header` class). I suppose the OP is looking for collapsible details instead. They should be added directly to the `advanced` element by using the `'#group' => 'advanced'` property. Call me nitpicker, but answers at DA remain for everybody with similar issues. For earning my vote, please edit your answer.

Comment: Thanks Mario. I've corrected the example.

Comment: Thanks Brad and Mario. Going to give this a try and report back!

Comment: This answer is close, but not quite a 100% solution, because as written, this will just move the vertical tabs to the sidebar (screenshot https://i.imgur.com/hvxGNI6.png). I'm trying to figure out what the Node form does specifically to ensure the 'advanced' form item doesn't get turned into a vertical tab, but cannot figure it out.

Comment: I've discovered that Seven (the default admin theme) changes the `#type` of `advanced` from `vertical_tabs` to a simple `container` in `seven_form_node_form_alter`. I've updated the example code to do the same. (Without help from the admin theme's alter function, NodeForm would happily let the advanced panel render as vertical tabs.)